# notification when Formio ngFormBuilder components are added to builder

Tags: formio

Using Formio ngFormBuilder (ng-formio-builder v2.26.0) and want to be notified when components (specifically my custom components) are added or removed from the builder-UI/dropzone.

The events that I did find in the source code do not seem to propagate to my listeners. e.g. emit not called on $rootScope -> $scope.$emit('formUpdate', ...)

I could not find any API events that worked for me.

Any suggestions?

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Decided to set an angular watch on the form components passed to formio-builder and was able to determine when components were added or removed from the form.